# Relation between matrices

Tags: plotting, graphics, matrix, linear-algebra

Maybe this is not a usual question for this forum... I have the following two matrices, mat1 and mat2, respectively:

```
mat1={{0.0178885,-0.0178885,-0.00894427,0.00894427,0.,0.,-0.00894427,0.00894427,0.,0.},{-0.0178885,0.0178885,0.00894427,-0.00894427,0.,0.,0.00894427,-0.00894427,0.,0.},{-0.00894427,0.00894427,0.0178885,-0.0178885,-0.00894427,0.00894427,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.00894427,-0.00894427,-0.0178885,0.0178885,0.00894427,-0.00894427,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,-0.00894427,0.00894427,0.00894427,-0.00894427,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.00894427,-0.00894427,-0.00894427,0.00894427,0.,0.,0.,0.},{-0.00894427,0.00894427,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.0178885,-0.0178885,-0.00894427,0.00894427},{0.00894427,-0.00894427,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.0178885,0.0178885,0.00894427,-0.00894427},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.00894427,0.00894427,0.00894427,-0.00894427},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.00894427,-0.00894427,-0.00894427,0.00894427}};
mat2={{0.0198382,-0.0198382,-0.00991908,0.00991908,0.,0.,-0.00991908,0.00991908,0.,0.},{-0.0198382,0.0198382,0.00991908,-0.00991908,0.,0.,0.00991908,-0.00991908,0.,0.},{-0.00991908,0.00991908,0.0203862,-0.0203862,-0.0104672,0.0104672,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.00991908,-0.00991908,-0.0203862,0.0203862,0.0104672,-0.0104672,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,-0.0104672,0.0104672,0.0104672,-0.0104672,0.,0.,0.,0.},{0.,0.,0.0104672,-0.0104672,-0.0104672,0.0104672,0.,0.,0.,0.},{-0.00991908,0.00991908,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.0203862,-0.0203862,-0.0104672,0.0104672},{0.00991908,-0.00991908,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.0203862,0.0203862,0.0104672,-0.0104672},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,-0.0104672,0.0104672,0.0104672,-0.0104672},{0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.0104672,-0.0104672,-0.0104672,0.0104672}};
```

If I plot the matrices, as well as their ratio, I obtain a visual representation of these:

```
Quiet@List[MatrixPlot[mat1], MatrixPlot[mat2], MatrixPlot[mat1/mat2]]
```

I think that there exists a numerical relation between mat1 and mat2, but I can't find it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Should your `Dssmt` and `Dss` be the same thing?

Comment: @Roman there is a numerical relation among them, but it isn't a simple scaling operation by means of a scalar

Comment: Please make your code self-contained so that people can help without needing to guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numerically all 100 differences between 100 corresponding elements of matrices correspond fall into just 5 symmetric values:

```
Round[Union[Flatten[mat1-mat2]],.0001]
```

> {-0.0025,-0.0019,-0.0015,-0.001,0.,0.001,0.0015,0.0019,0.0025}

Which looks a lot like some small noise imposed on:

```
{-25,-20,-15,-10,0,10,15,20,25}/10000
```

It is actually quite easy to understand if you visualize your data. First of all you can see that the values of both matrices follow each other closely

```
ListPlot3D[{mat1,mat2},InterpolationOrder->0,PlotStyle->{Red,Blue},
BoxRatios->1,Mesh->None,SphericalRegion->True,PlotLegends->{"mat1","mat1"}]
```

[image]

You can see the also see the differences and realize, - for some elements mat1 is greater (more red), sometimes mat (more blue), and sometimes the same (white):

```
ListPlot3D[Rescale[Ds-Dss],InterpolationOrder->0,ColorFunction->
"TemperatureMap",BoxRatios->1,Mesh->None,SphericalRegion->True]
```

[image]

You also can see that all total

```
In[]:= Length[Flatten[mat1-mat2]]
Out[]= 100
```

differences between corresponding elements fall into just 9 different values and if you take in account symmetry - just 5 values:

```
BarChart[Union[Flatten[mat1 - mat2]], PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

-- lets call them levels. And now you can find the statistics of how many differences correspond to a specific level -- and see it is symmetric:

```
ListLinePlot[Sort[Tally[Flatten[mat1 - mat2]]], PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Business"]
```

[image]